# Determine if $f(x,y)=(1+x+2y)^2$ is differentiable in $(1,-1).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To show this, I can use the definition for differentiability for two variables:

> *A function* $f(x,y)$ *of two variables is differentiable in* $(x,y)=(a,b)$ *iff* $ \ \exists \ $ *constants* $A,B:$
>
> $$f(1+h,1+k)-f(a,b)=Ah+Bk+\sqrt{h^2+k^2} \ \rho(h,k).$$

Here I go:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x,y)       & = & (1+x+2y)^2 \\
f(1,-1)      & = & (1+1+2(-2))^2=0 \\
f(1+h,-1+k)  & = & (1+1+h+2(-1+k))^2=4k^2+4kh+h^2.
\end{array}$$

$$\implies f(1+h,-1+k)-f(1,-1)=4k^2+4kh+h^2=Ah+Bk+\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\rho(h,k) \quad (1).$$

Clearly, there exists no constants $A,B$ such that $(1)$ holds, thus, the function is not differentiable in $(1,-1).$

**Questions:**

1. Will my answer do?
2. How can I show whether this function is $C^1$ or not?

Comment: What about $A=B=0$ then $h^2,k^2,hk$ are all three $o(||(h,k)||)$.

Comment: @zwim What? I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: I say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2+2x+4y\big|_{(1,-1)}=0$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=4+4x+8y\big|_{(1,-1)}=0$ so it is expected to find $A=0$ and $B=0$. Now the terms in $h^2,k^2,hk$ are all negligible in regard to $h,k$, they are second order, this is what $o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})$ means.

Comment: @Parseval Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. If polynomials were not differentiable we would have given up differential calculus long ago. Your problem is that you don't yet have fully grasped the notion of differentiability in the multivariate case.

A simple calculation gives 
$$f(1+h,-1+k)-f(1,-1)=(h+2k)^2=0h +0k +h^2+4hk+4k^2\ .$$
Now $(2|h|-|k|)^2\geq0$ and therefore $4|hk|\leq 4h^2+k^2$ It follows that
$${|f(1+h,-1+k)-f(1,-1)|\over\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\leq5\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\to0\qquad\bigl((h,k)\to(0,0)\bigr)\ .$$
This shows that $df(1,-1)=0\ .$

Of course this is all obvious using the standard rules of this game.

Comment: How did you get the 5 there? I don't understand the inequality.

Comment: @Parseval Why pick on a detail? If you can show the upper bound with $42$ replacing $5$, you are done. So prove it with $42$ if you prefer...

Comment: We have not covered Schwartz inequality. Is there another way to show this?

Comment: yes, $(h-k)^2\ge 0$ so $2hk\le h^2+k^2$ so $(h+2k)^2=h^2+4hk+4k^2\le 3h^2+6k^2\le 6(h^2+k^2)$

Comment: @zwim: Thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in this case you can simply observethat by **Differentiability theorem** since all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ then (i.e. sufficient condition) the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Note that when  partial derivatives are not continuos at (0,0) you can't yet conclude anything about differentiability. You need to **check directly differentiability by definition** that:

$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\| f(h,k)-f(0,0)-(f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))\cdot (h,k)\|}{\| (h,k)\|}=0$$